# Openpyxl reads and returns a None every second cell

Tags: python, openpyxl, import-from-excel

I'm trying to read a xlsx using the load_workbook method and it works fairly well. However, if there is an Empty cell in a column and the workbook is loaded with "use_iterators or read_only" option set, the rows() method adds a 'None' value to the output after every original cell value in that column. If there are no empty cells in the column within the data range, then there is no problem.

Please find below the piece of code and the data of the excel file I'm reading from:

Excel file: book1.xlsx

Data range:
(Column A, row 1-7)

empty cell

1

empty cell

2

3

4

5

### Code:

```
  Book=openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='book1.xlsx', read_only=True, data_only=True)
  ws=Book.get_sheet_by_name('sheet1')
  for row in ws.rows:
      for col in row:
           print col.value
```

### Actual Output (when read_only option is true):

None

1

None

None

2

None

3

None

4

None

5

### Expected Output:

None

1

None

2

3

4

5

I still couldn't resolve of this as I'm still facing the same issue. Please excuse me for any naive errors. I'm new to python and openpyxl and I'm here just looking for an answer to the problem. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The same question was also asked (and answered) on the mailing list. The user is deviating unnecessarily from the API and creating additional cells in the range.

Comment: Thanks for your advice on correcting the code Charlie. However, even after those corrections, I'm still having the same issue when I open the workbook in readonly mode. It would be highly helpful if you can help me resolve this. Thanks again.

Comment: @charlie, as you just agreed and confirmed that this is a bug (google groups mailing list), can you please revert the downvote? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the confirmation from "Charlie Clark" (in openpyxl google groups), this is a bug in the current version of openpyxl. This is applicable to any worksheet with empty rows due a counter not being updated. This is Fixed in the 2.2 branch and will be in 2.2.1 when released.